# Perl - Copy a file (and contents) to remote server with Net:FTP and Possible Net::FTP::File

Tags: perl, ftp, net-library

I am having a whole lot of trouble copying a file from one server to another.

I have been trying for two days.

Please know I am using strict and the below script is just for testing.

I actually get a files "name" onto the "remote" server and chmod to 0755 but it is empty.

1- The file needs to be copied/ftp'd to a "remote" servers specific directory. mkdir if !.

2- The "local" file to be copied exists in a directory other than the scripts directory.

3- After the file is copied to "remote" server, chmod it to 0755.

4- Easy for seemingly everyone but me. :-(

Below writes the file in name only, it is empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print CGI::header();
use Net::FTP;
use Net::FTP::File;
#use strict;
my $host='ftp.myserver.com';
my $ftp=Net::FTP->new($host,Timeout=>240,Passsive=>1) or $newerr=1;
push @ERRORS, "Can't ftp to $host: $!\n" if $newerr;
myerr() if $newerr;
print qq~Connected<br />~;
$ftp->login('cherry@myserver.com','mypasswd') or die "Cannot login: $@";
$datedir ='04-01-2011';

#################################
$copyfrom = $datedir;
$thisfile = 'index.pl';
$fullpath = $copyfrom.'/'.$thisfile;
$path = '/home/account/public_html/folder/'.$copyfrom;
if (-e $fullpath) {print qq~Copy source exists<br >~;} 
unless (-e $fullpath) {print qq~Copy source does not exist<br >~;} 

#######################################################
my $isdir = $ftp->isdir($datedir);
if (!$isdir){
    print qq~Remote directory does not exist<br >~;
    $ftp->mkdir($datedir) or die $ftp->message;
}
if ($isdir){
    print qq~Remote directory exists<br />~;
}

#############
my $new = $datedir.'/'.$thisfile;
my $isfile = $ftp->exists($new);
if (!$isfile){
    print qq~Remote file does not exist<br />~;
    $ftp->cwd($copyfrom);
    print "I'm in the directory ", $ftp->pwd(), "\n";
    my $chkdir = $ftp->isdir($copyfrom);
    if ($chkdir){print qq~directory exists<br />~;}
    if (!$chkdir){print qq~directory does not exists<br />~;}
    $ftp->ascii() || die $ftp->message;
    $ftp->put($copyfrom, $thisfile) or die $ftp->message;
    $ftp->chmod(755, $thisfile) or warn $ftp->message;
}
if ($isfile){
    print qq~Remote file exists<br >~;
}

$ftp->quit;


sub myerr {
  print "Error: \n";
  print @ERRORS;
  exit 0;
}
```

Now, I also just tried Net::FTP::File and copy(); but, errors to browser -- Software Error "current working directory "/" ".

I have read and read tested and tested until, I find myself here.

Besides the choice of modules (I read elsewhere), what am I doing wrong?

The servers are shared servers with cpanel so, I am pretty restricted therefore, I tried these ftp modules.

I am open to a fix of my script or a whole different approach that will work on my servers.

Thanks so much for any assistance..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I put on a blindfold and throw some darts, I will eventually hit a bull.

I did not really answer my own question but, threw the dart to the right spot.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
##########
use CGI;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print CGI::header();
use Net::FTP;
use Net::FTP::File;
######################################
my $host='ftp.mysite.com';
my $username = 'cherry@mysite.com';
my $password='MycAmelsPasSwoRD';
my $dateDir ='2011-03-25';
my $path = '/home/account/public_html/localfolder/inthisfolder';
my $directory = $path.'/'.$dateDir;
my $scriptfile= 'somescript.pl';
my $file = $path.'/'.$dateDir.'/'.$scriptfile;
#################################
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host,Timeout=>240,Passsive=>1) or die "Cannot connect to hostname: $@";
$ftp->login($username, $password)  or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->mkdir($dateDir) or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($dateDir) or die  $ftp->message;
#$ftp->ascii();
$ftp->put($file) or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->chmod(755,$scriptfile) or die $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit();
```

I do find useful info at stackoverflow all the time, a lifesaver!

Hopefully someone will find this code I posted useful!

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Use `isfile` instead of `exits` when testing if a file exists.
- Why do you never use `else`s?
- `$path` is never used (`$path` and `$fullpath` confusion?.
- Shouldn't your program `die` if local file didn't exist?
- If remote file doesn't exist, you `cwd` to `$copyfrom` instead of to `$datedir`.
- You are testing (isdir) `$copyfrom` existence after `cwd`ing to `$copyfrom`, so you are really testing for `/$copyfrom/$copyfrom`. Is this really what you want to do?
- Almost nobody should need to set `ascii` mode.

BTW, try disabling passive mode, and try enabling debug

```
my $ftp=Net::FTP->new($host,Timeout=>240, Debug=>1) or $newerr=1;
```

Comment: yeah, the question was a mess. I should not have put the dir and file tests in the question to begin with. Those were just idiot checks for me. I usually aways use elsif and else where req'd. That code was really just a conglomeration of frustrated attempts. As far as ascii, will taking that out be ok since it MUST me an ascii xfer?

Comment: Binary mode always transmits raw bytes, so the transferred file is identical to the original. Ascii mode is something archaic, don't use it.